# How to change this script to not to delete but replace with empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have this Script:

```
function Copy() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses')
    var range = sh.getDataRange().offset(1, 0);
    var data = range.getValues();
    var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('x').getSheetByName('backup')
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    sh.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
}
```

How should I change it to not delete that that line but replace it with empty cells?
Because I'm referring to those cells in another sheet and every time after the script runs those references got to #referror. And I'm guessing its because of the deleting.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to clear cell values but you don't want to delete rows by `sh.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);`. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? You can achieve it using `clear()`.

#### From :

```
sh.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
```

#### To :

```
sh.getRange(2, 1, range.getNumRows() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clear();
```

#### Reference :

- [clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.